# set flexbox width for first div about 85% and 15% for the second one

Tags: css, flexbox

I've flex container and 2 divs inside. I need to set width for it, about ~85% for first and ~15% for second, like on pic. How can i achieve this using flex-grow\shrink or smth?[image]

Comment: I'm missing your code in the question... could you please add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I think grow and shrink should do it. Allow me to try;

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.div1 {
  flex-grow: 85;
}

.div2 {
  flex-grow: 15;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="div div1"></div>
  <div class="div div2"></div>
</div>
```

Also possible using `float` and the more traditional `width`, but it requires clearing the float afterwards.

```css
.after-container {
  clear: both;
}

.div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  width: 85%;
}

.div2 {
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div div1"></div>
  <div class="div div2"></div>
</div>
<div class="after-container"></div>
```